# Double Iteration Intersect in Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, intersect

I need to intersect two highly-overlapping shapefiles, the first with 60 polygons (ponds), the second with 3000 (lilly pads). A straight-up intersection does not work (60 x 3000 -- it runs for hours and fails. Even 1x3000 does not work). Hence, I have believe the solution to be a model with double iteration: for every pond, iterate and intersect with every lilly pad. These will be merged together at the end. Because there cannot be two iterators in a single model, I have made a main model with a nested sub-model:

Main Model- Iterate through every Lilly pad and Intersect it with EVERY pond (output from the sub-model IterateSupply2)

[image]

Sub Model (IterateSupply2) - Iterate through every pond, copy features so they can be the model parameter (and output)

[image]

This double iteration isn't working for me: instead of 60x3000, it only gives me 1x3000. I have tried various preconditions, but don't understand how they would influence a process like this.

To explain in a different way: I would like for the main model to loop through using one submodel output, before moving onto the next submodel output and looping again

Comment: Did you try a straight intersection, and have it failed to know it will not work?  That really seems like what you are looking for in this situation.  If that has proven not to work, then your model need not be quite so complex.  Simply iterate over one layer, and the features be the one input of an intersection, where the other input is the other layer in question.  If you can, append the results together to a final output layer.  If it is easier, create a series of output layers for each iterated input feature, then merge these layers together at the end to create your final product.

Comment: How do you know that simple 2 layers interest is not working? Seems outmost basic thing for ArcGis

Comment: -1 on this one because you overcomplicated it and showing no respect to other users efforts to help you. On every single post of yours I found no feedback from you.

Comment: @Get Spatial -- yes I tried a straight intersection. It runs for 6 hours and fails. Even if I only use 1 pond to intersect 3000 lillypads it fails -- too many sliver polygons. Perhaps the analogy isn't accurate. It's more like 3000 carpets piled on top of each other, slightly offset

Comment: @FelixIP -- when there are many polygons overlapping, intersect does not work well, or at all. I don't believe I am overcomplicating.

Comment: I think that @FelixIP has a point in that you are overcomplicating the solution.  If a process is failing due to excessive processing, I don't think a model that is more complex will work any better.  If a 2 file intersect won't work, then break it up.  Take half of each file and work with that, then do the other half, the intersect them together.  You need to break it down until you get something to work, then build from there.
The other option might be to try different software.  [QGIS](http://qgis.org) is free, and equally good.  Use the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) installer.

Comment: Something else to try would be a different file format.  Sometimes shapefiles are not as good for this sort of processing.  Perhaps load into a File GDB or something else.  Try simple things first, then build up to a model if all else fails.

Comment: @GetSpatial -- I will try the GDB. But even if I broke it up (1 x 500) x 60 x 6, that's too much clicking. Especially if I have to do this to 20 datasets. Double iteration makes sense to me

Comment: If you can build a model to do a double iteration over something, you can build a model to cycle through some datasets, intersect them and put them back together again.
I've given you at least 4 different things to try.  If one of them works, then it can be adapted for as many datasets as you have.  Again, keep it simple.  With your model, it is very unclear how it fits together, and what you are trying to do with each iterator.  Please edit your post to explain the model step by step, then, if all else fails, someone might take a look at it.

Comment: Intersect designed to work with overlaps. No overlaps produce empty output. What are trying to achieve really?

Comment: @GetSpatial -- I edited my post a bit, I hope it's more clear. I appreciate your time spent on this. I'm asking the question because I can't make a model that double iterates over something.

Comment: @FelixIP -- Yes, but not so many overlaps. OK, imagine a 20 minute road network catchment at every city intersection (3000) intersected by other catchments (60). I want to find the overlap between each

Comment: This is exactly what intersect will do. Each feature will have attributes of parents.

Comment: Dissolve output using two fields, unique names of 1st and 2 nd